# Web3 formatter.js loading issue

Tags: webpack, next.js, web3js

I am trying to create a small ethereum blockchain application with NextJS.

Import Web3 is causing some issue

```
ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: C:\Path\node_modules\web3-core-helpers\lib\formatters.js Unexpected token (296:20)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     // If options !== undefined, don't blow out existing data
|     if (options.fromBlock === undefined)
|         options = { ...options, fromBlock: 'latest' };
|     if (options.fromBlock || options.fromBlock === 0)
|         options.fromBlock = inputBlockNumberFormatter(options.fromBlock);
    at C:\Path\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:303:19
    at C:\Path\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:209:11
    at C:\Path\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:373:3
    at iterateNormalLoaders (C:\Path\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
    at C:\Path\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:205:4
    at C:\Path\node_modules\enhanced-resolve\lib\CachedInputFileSystem.js:70:14
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

The `import Web3 from "web3";` is the root cause

```
import Web3 from "web3";

const web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);

export default web3;
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha",
    "dev": "next dev"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@truffle/hdwallet-provider": "^1.2.2",
    "fs-extra": "^9.1.0",
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
    "mocha": "^8.3.0",
    "next": "^4.1.4",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "solc": "^0.4.17",
    "web3": "^1.3.4"
  }
}
```

Do I need other module ?
I noticed that the same import is working when creating the app with npx create-next-app but I want to use specific version so I only used `npm install --save next@4.1.4 react@16 react-dom@16` inside my node project.

Comment: Probably unrelated, but any reason to use an extremely old version of Next.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this error is pretty visible in the message, its probably because of the `...` notation in newer javascript, as the next you're using is old, it doesnt make sense of it. you have 3 options (I did the 3rd one)

1. change that bit of code to old syntax using `options = Object.assign(options, {fromBlock: latest})`
2. use newer next which can implement new syntax
3. use older web3 which doesn't use new syntax, @1.2.9 works. dont forget to `npm install`

Comment: Hi @Yash I am encountering this issue. Downgrading works as you have suggested, but there are hundreds of vulnerabilities reported by npm audit when using version 1.2.9. How did you solve this problem?

Comment: yes, as a smart contract developer, you'll find a lot of tooling that you use have many vulnerabilities as they're using a lot of outdated packages probably. there's no solution to it. I can suggest use the latest versions, they generally have lesser

Answer (score 2):

Use Web3 v1.2.9

Worked for me!

Comment: This solution worked for me. I am following Stephen Grider's tutorial, and in section 7, building the Kickstarter clone, I found this error. Changing the package.json to include web 1.2.9 and running `npm install` solved the issue for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issues, and it seemed I was able to resolve it by updating next using the command "npm install next@10.0.7"

I came to this solution after running "npm audit" and it recommending the aforementioned command to resolve various dependency issues.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

use `Object.assign` to replace the value

Comment: @SevenYa welcome to SO! please don't use screenshots as answers. Paste your code and format accordingly.